# How to identify PCA components in Embedding visualizer

Tags: pca, tensorboard

I am trying to analyze some data (some 1d vectors) using the PCA tool in Tensorboard's embedding projector. I'd like to know if there is any way to label the tensor individual components so I am able to identify which ones describe the most variance.

This is my code for the embedding, in which I have a list of variables called 'variables'.

```
create embeddings and write
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver = tf.train.Saver(variables)
    for var in variables:
        sess.run(var.initializer)
    saver.save(sess, os.path.join(logdir, 'images.ckpt'))

    config = projector.ProjectorConfig()
    for var in variables:
        # One can add multiple embeddings.
        embedding = config.embeddings.add()
        embedding.tensor_name = var.name
        # Link this tensor to its metadata file (e.g. labels).
        embedding.metadata_path = metadata
        # Saves a config file that TensorBoard will read during startup.
    projector.visualize_embeddings(tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir), config)
```

I want to label "Component #1", "Component #2" and so on so I could match that with one vector position.

[image]